Why is explicitly typing the array as BinaryFloatingPoint necessary?
This does not compile (however Double does conform to BinaryFloatingPoint):
extension Array where Element == any BinaryFloatingPoint {
    var mean: Double? {
        if isEmpty { return nil }
        return reduce(0.0) { ret, x in ret + Double(x) } / Double(count)
    }
}

let d = [2.3, 4.5]
print(d.mean!) // No exact matches in reference to property 'mean'

To compile, I must do this:
let d: [any BinaryFloatingPoint] = [2.3, 4.5]
I'm having some difficulty understanding why this is. When an attempt to DRY requires that you add type statements at call sites, it feels like the purpose is defeated. Is there a way to improve this implementation?

You can’t use a specific type when you say the computed property in the extension can be used for a protocol. So make use of the generic type Element and the protocol
extension Array where Element: BinaryFloatingPoint {
    var mean: Element? {
        if isEmpty { return nil }
        return reduce(.zero) { ret, x in ret + x } / Element(count)
    }
}

And you could extend it to be an extension to Collection instead

thanks, I also had a very bad typo: Element == any BinaryFloatingPoint

Joakim's answer fixes the problem but doesn't really explain what the issue is.
The problem is that the line
let d = [2.3, 4.5]

implicitly infers the type of d to be Array<Double> not Array<any BinaryFloatingPoint> and Double and any BinaryFloatingPoint are not equivalent types, so the extension does not apply to d.
Joakim's fix expands the "scope" of the extension to apply to arrays of any type that conforms to BinaryFloatingPoint at the expense of not being able to have heterogeneously typed elements i.e. Array<any BinaryFloatingPoint> can contain a mix of Float and Double but Array<T> where T: BinaryFloatingPoint can only contain elements of type T.
